# How would I use a method from another class?

Tags: iphone, xcode, objective-c++

I have a class with a specific uisearchbar method.. How would I use the same method in another view (i.e. another class) that has another uisearchbar... Besides simply copying over the code? Would subclassing work in this case?

Thanks

Comment: Can it be made into a category on UISearchBar?

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work and will result in more code since I also want to duplicate methods for the table view defined in the initial class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it as a method in the App delegate.You can access the app delegate in any of the views.
[I know its ugly, but it seems the simplest way, If subclassing or category are too much of an overhead.]